# How do i add a splash screen to an xcode project?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I am trying to add a splash screen to an xcode project?
It may potentially be an animation with sound effects.

Can anyone help?

Thank you guys.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

According to apple's guideline it is not possible to use gif as splash screen or launch image.

If you are using story board for launch screen (> ios 7) then you can use jpg but below or equal version to ios 7, you have only option is png.

You can achieve animation kind of startup by making your first view controller animated and make it work as splash scree. In this case you should not set any splash image of launch screen storyboard(or set black background color), so it will show black screen for a second when app will be launching and then your first view controller will be animate and your app will got startup with animation or gif.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Probably the better approach is to make your launch storyboard exactly the same as the first image of your actual "splash" scene, that way you get a still image that then animates rather than a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

Basically - you can't make animated splash screen. However - you can duplicate it (LaunchScreen) in storyboard and make it as entrance VC of your app. Than when view gets loaded - start your animation.

As a final result you will have "animating splash screen": App starts -> static launch screen -> transition to entrance VC which won't be visible by user because scenes look the same -> entrance VC view is loaded so as animation.

For sum up: treat your launch screen's xib as first frame of an animation

Answer (score 0):

You can't make splash screen animated with sound effect.

But it is possible if you make a fake splash screen that you will have full ability to make any animation and sound effect.

For example, add a real splash screen with white background color, and make your fake splash screen appear after with white background color also. So that your entire splash screen will look smooth from real splash screen to fake splash screen.